# Swift constraint doesnot change in Autolayout while hiding views

Tags: ios, swift

These are my codes
     //My UIViews

```
@IBOutlet weak var UIVIewFirst: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var UIViewSecond: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var UIViewThird: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var middleViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var ViewThirdHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

There is a button to show and hide the view as;

```
    @IBAction func infoClicked(sender: SSRadioButton) {
    if UIViewSecond.hidden {
        sender.selected = false
        UIViewSecond.hidden = false
        self.middleViewHeightConstraint.constant = 134

    } else {
        sender.selected = true
        UIViewSecond.hidden = true
        self.middleViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        self.ViewThirdHeight.constant = 180
    }
}
```

the vertical gap between each view is 10. After hiding the view the gap becomes 20. But i need it to set it 10 between third and second view. Even though i set the third view height constant to any number it does not changes it position.Can anyone suggest why is this happening??

Comment: use `view.setNeedsLayout()` at the end of modifying constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the outlet connection of the `vertical spacing` constraint between either `First-Second` or `Second-Third` views. Also if you want to hide/show only `Second view`, you don't need to do any changes to `Third View height constraint`.

Say For example, we take the outlet of `vertical spacing between First and Second views`, then:

```
@IBOutlet weak var UIVIewFirst: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var UIViewSecond: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var middleViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var verticalSpacingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBAction func infoClicked(sender: UIButton)
{
    if UIViewSecond.hidden
    {
        sender.selected = false
        UIViewSecond.hidden = false
        self.middleViewHeightConstraint.constant = 134
        self.verticalSpacingConstraint.constant = 10
    }
    else
    {
        sender.selected = true
        UIViewSecond.hidden = true
        self.middleViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0
        self.verticalSpacingConstraint.constant = 0
    }
}
```

Below are the screenshots of output:

**1. When button is not selected**

[image]

**2. When button is selected**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Constraints ignore the `hidden` property.

If possible for your requirements, embedd your views within a `UIStackView`.

See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40643051/1457385).

Answer (score 1):

You have not tell your view to update the view with the new constraint, you have to call this code:

`self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: where should i add this??please elaborate..And does this support Autolayout?

Comment: just after the code above, after you change your constraint you have to call this, and yes, this tell your auto layout to layout again with new constraint

Comment: It should be working, if not then your constraint is wrong or it just doesnt change anything

Comment: I have added it after  self.middleViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0. it does not changes any thing.

Comment: It may matter what type of subviews are in the view. I learned the hard way last night that UISlider, even when hidden, has an intrinsic width no matter what. My only solution (so far) is to "live with it".

Answer (score 1):

```
firstView
   | gap = 10
secondView
   | gap = 10
thirdView
```

after removing `secondView`

```
    firstView
       | gap = 10
  ---------- height = 0
       | gap = 10
   thirdView
```

so the gap becomes 20

try to add constraint programmatically after hiding the view or decrease any one gap.

Comment: Yes i know how the gap becomes 20. But i have given the constraints for third view and it's not working

Comment: try using `setNeedsLayout()` at the end of modifying constraints

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the frame of the view instead of changing the constraint, also do view.layoutIfNeeded after making any changes.

Comment: If you are using AutoLayout, changing a view's frame has no impact.

Comment: It worked for me that is why I suggested to try this because it happened to me sometimes that when I try to change the constraint does nothing but changing the frame does.