# Aligning 3 buttons with dynamic contents in objective C using Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, intrinsic-content-size

I have 3 buttons one below the other.The requirement is , all should be centrally aligned.Also the dynamic contents should fit in these 3 buttons.Please help me with this issue. I have only a vague understanding about content hugging, compression resistance and intrinsic content size.Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use stack view for buttons  and set that stack view in centre. for dynamic content set stackviews heightConstraint gretaer than equal relation.

Comment: @Vishal:Hi Vishal, Thank you for your comment.Could you please tell me about the implementation of the same, below iOS 9?

Comment: It will be same. Just use UIView Instead of stackView. Apply same height and same width constraint to all buttons and deal with height constraint  of the container UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For `iOS 9` and later:**

Use `UIStackView` to embed all your `buttons` and set that `stack view` in centre of the `view`. For dynamic content, set `stackView's` `heightConstraint` greater than equal `relation` (>=).

**For `iOS 8` and earlier:**

Just use `UIView` Instead of `UIStackView`. Rest of the things will be same.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Embed all `UIBUtton`s within a `UIStackView` and set the stackViews properties to you needs.

To get the idea, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40643051/1457385).

Note: `UIStackView` is only available under iOS >= 9.

Comment: Depending on the iOS he needs to support. Stackviews are only available on iOS 9+ if that is not a problem then yes the easiest would be using stackview.

Comment: @Pancho: Correct. Added hint to  answer.

Comment: What can be done if the version is < iOS 9? Thank you very much for your answer and comments.

Comment: @shallowThought: Thank you very much for your help.